# How to find match with surrounding words?

Tags: text-processing

I want to find match with surrounding words. *I also want it to be fast.*

Here's what I've got:

`grep -o -P '(\w+ ){0,n}match( \w+){0,m}'`

n is number of words before the phrase, m is number of words after the phrase. match is the phrase I'm looking for.

Is there some faster way of doing that?

example:

`echo word1 word2 word3 123 word4 word5 word6 | grep -o -P '(\w+ ){0,2}123( \w+){0,2}'`

=> `word2 word3 123 word4 word5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(\w+ )` will match a word or part of word.  This means that `grep` will treat every character in every word as a potential start-of-match.  In your example, it will consider each of

- `word1`
- `ord1`
- `rd1`
- `d1`
- `1`

before moving on to the successful match (starting at `word2`).

As you are interested in finding whole words, you can prevent all the attempted mid-word matches by including word boundaries in the pattern:

```
grep -P '\<(\w+ ){0,2}123( \w+){0,2}\>'
```

Another effect of this is to prevent matching `123` when it appears inside a longer word.

This cut the time by a factor of 100 for me (test case: searching for the word 'me' in Ulysses)

The "Pitfalls" section of http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html has some good pointers on what makes regexps slow.